# How do I look up a date that fall in between date ranges and return the value in the next cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to get look up a date from one sheet1 in sheet2.  The dates on sheets 2 are located column A with a value I want to bring back in column B.  How do I do this?

Sheet1  Column A Hire Data

Sheet2 Column A - Pay dates

Sheet 2 Column B - a number value

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect an exact match? If so try `VLOOKUP` function like this in sheet 1 B2

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)`

If you want a "closest match" and Pay Dates are in ascending order you can change the 0 to a 1, i.e.

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,1)`